# How to remove label nodes from a scene when not in use to save memory usage in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory, sprite-kit

I am having a memory issue in a scene that is mainly just labels. My app is educational and this is basically a scene with topic buttons on the left and different paragraphs of text to scroll through depending on which topic is selected.

I'm just using "exampleLabel.alpha =" to show or hide text based on the topic selection and when you select different topics, the memory usage just keeps going up and up until the application crashes. I've searched through SO and can't figure out a way to solve this issue.

Each topic has its own SkLabelNodes that become visible when selected.

EXMAPLE CODE:

```
var topic1Label = SKLabelNode()
var topic2Label - SKLabelNode()

topic1Label = self.childNode(withName: "topic1Label") as! SKLabelNode
topic2Label = self.childNode(withName: "topic2Label") as! SKLabelNode

//touches ended
if nodesArray.first?.name == "topic1" {
topic1Label.alpha = 1
topic2Label.alpha = 0
}
if nodesArray.first?.name == "topic2" {
topic1Label.alpha = 0
topic2Label.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: Why not just use SwiftUI or UIKit for something like this? If you're not simulating physics with SpriteKit, then why use SpriteKit? Also, you might want to try using `as?` instead of `as!` because the latter can crash your app.

Comment: This more sounds like a memory leak